# Templated C++ function with the first argument set to the second as default argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a function like this:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
void foo(const B & b)
{
    ...
}
```

`A` should be optional; if not explicitly defined in the function call, it should be set to `B`. The intent is to avoid unnecessarily verbose code:

```
int i;

// First variant: A is specified explicitly
foo<float>(i);

// Second variant: A is set to B implicitly
// This is because foo < int > (i) is unnecessarily verbose
foo(i);
```

However, I haven't found a way to do that yet. Can anybody come up with one?

Comment: Which c++ version is this?

Comment: That is C++14 .

Comment: Why do you need two template parameters? The example looks like you only need `B`.

Comment: Template arguments are positional, if you can flip B and A you can do this via just calling the two parameter version from the single parameter version. The compiler will optimize the rest

Comment: template < typename B, typename A = B > ?

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev That stops `foo<float>(i);` from being able to work.

Comment: @NathanOliver, sorry, why does it stop `foo<float>(i);`?

Comment: @IgorG Because you are then explicitly specifying `B`, not `A`. `foo<float>(i);` leads to `A` = `B` = `float` instead of `B` = `int` and `A` = `float`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct deduce_tag;

template <typename PreA = deduce_tag, typename B>
void foo(const B & b) {
    using A = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_same<PreA, deduce_tag>::value,
        B,
        PreA
    >;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I always forget that default template argument don't need to be trailing like default function arguments.